# Convert All Items in a Dataframe to Float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert all items in my dataframe to a float. The types are varies at the moment. The following error persist -> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '116,584.54'

The file can be found at https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2019/01/weodata/WEOApr2019all.xls

I checked the value in excel, it is a Number. I tried .replace, .astype, pd.to_numeric.

```py
for i in weo['1980']:
    if i == float:
        print(i)
        i.replace(",",'')
        i.replace("--",np.nan)
    else:
        continue
```

Also, I have tried:

```py
weo['1980'] = weo['1980'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: numbers do not have `,` in python. Try adding the `thousands=','` argument when you read the csv, instead of fixing this after the fact.

Comment: numbers do not have , in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) in order to conduct the conversion which is usually the recommended approach. As you already attempted in your question, you may have to remove all the comas form the string in column 1980 first as it may cause the same error as quoted in your question:

```
weo['1980'] = weo['1980'].replace(',', '')
weo['1980'] = weo['1980'].asytpe(float)
```

If you're reading your DataFrame from Excel using [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), you can also specify the `thousands` argument to do this conversion for you which will likely result in a higher performance:

```
pandas.read_excel(file, thousands=',')
```

Answer (score -1):

I had types error all the time while playing with dataframes. I now always use this to convert all the values that can be converted into floats.

```py
# Convert all columns that can be converted into float into float.
# Error were raised because their type was Object
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: With this approach the OP will loose all values over 1,000 due to the thousands separator.